# Displaying large amount of data in QTableview

Tags: c++, gridview, qt5, row, qtableview

In my project, I need to display around a million rows of data in QTableView. To optimize the process, I would like to load only 1000 rows at a time, and more when scrolling down occurs at the last row. Please help me figure out a proper way to do this.

Comment: For this, you need to use the `QTableView` with a custom model i.e. a class derived from [QAbstractTableModel](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstracttablemodel.html). Then, you have to override (at least) [canFetchMore()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#canFetchMore) and [fetchMore()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#fetchMore). There is a [Fetch More Example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-itemviews-fetchmore-example.html) in the Qt doc.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. It helped me start the process. I am using canfetchmore() and fetchmore() with QAbstractItemModel. Now, In fetchmore(), I am trying to clear the model and refill the data. But, when model->clear() is called it internally calls the fetchmore() again. Any way to clear the model data without internally calling the fethmore().